# Create folder and subfolder in SharePoint 2013 using php

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, php

I am a fresher and want to use SharePoint 2013 with php. What I really want to do is create folders, sub-folders and write .xlsx files inside these folders and also want to read and download these files using php.
can anyone help me? 
**I only understand PHP and java-script.**

Answer (score 4):

You can create folders and subfolders using the Lists web service using the UpdateListItems method. The following example code takes a foldername argument and creates a folder in the root folder of the list. If you want to create a folder within another folder then just change the RootFolder attribute to the url of the folder. Hope this helped.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx

```
public static void UpdateListItemCreateFolder(string folderName)
{
        listservice.Lists listProxy = new listservice.Lists();

        string xmlconst = "<Batch OnError='Continue' 
RootFolder='http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1/tester2'><Method ID='1' 
Cmd='New'><Field Name='ID'>New</Field><Field Name='FSObjType'>1</Field>
<Field Name='BaseName'>!@foldername</Field></Method></Batch>";


        listProxy.Url = 
"http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
        listProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;


        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string xmlFolder = xmlconst.Replace("!@foldername", folderName);
        doc.LoadXml(xmlFolder);
        XmlNode batchNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Batch");
        XmlNode resultNode = listProxy.UpdateListItems("tester2", 
batchNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sara says, you can use list web services to create items in a document library. If you want to use only JavaScript, you can use SharePointPlus.js. This library allows you to use list web services via JavaScript.

https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/files.html#createFolder